# How do i make sure the changes i made in my JFrame stay even when i exit the frame

Tags: java, serialization, jframe, deserialization

So I'm making a seat reservation system in Java using swing and i want to save the seats reserved by a user
so that when another user opens the The seat reservation window he cant choose already chosen seats.
This is my first time asking so apologies for my lack of questioning etiqutte.

I tried to use the serializable interface to save the user input and then reopen it when another user logs in but when i try to log in with the other user the Frame for the seat reservation system doesnt open, Infact nothing even seems to happen.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserIDAndPasswords idandPasswords = new UserIDAndPasswords();
    UserLogin userlogin = new UserLogin(idandPasswords.getLoginInfo());

    }

}





public class UserIDAndPasswords {

    
    HashMap<String,String> logininfo = new HashMap<String,String>();
    
    UserIDAndPasswords(){
        
        logininfo.put("Zain","Hallelujah101");
        logininfo.put("Arsal","BakedCash222");
        logininfo.put("Basil","ABC123");
    }
    
    public HashMap getLoginInfo(){
        return logininfo;
    }
    
    
}






public class UserLogin implements ActionListener, Serializable {

     JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dubai Software Limited");
     JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome to JApp 01");
     JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
     JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
     JTextField userIDField = new JTextField();
     JPasswordField userPasswordField = new JPasswordField();
     JLabel userIDLabel = new JLabel("userID:");
     JLabel userPasswordLabel = new JLabel("password:");
     JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel();
     HashMap<String,String> logininfo = new HashMap<String,String>();
     
     UserLogin(HashMap<String, String> loginInfoOriginal){
         
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setSize(420,420);
         frame.setLayout(null);
         frame.setVisible(true);
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         
         label.setBounds(140,-120,200,400);
          
         
         logininfo = loginInfoOriginal;
            
            userIDLabel.setBounds(50,100,75,25);
            userPasswordLabel.setBounds(50,150,75,25);
            
            messageLabel.setBounds(125,250,250,35);
            
            userIDField.setBounds(125,100,200,25);
            userPasswordField.setBounds(125,150,200,25);
            
            loginButton.setBounds(125,200,100,25);
            loginButton.setFocusable(false);
            loginButton.addActionListener(this);
            
            resetButton.setBounds(225,200,100,25);
            resetButton.setFocusable(false);
            resetButton.addActionListener(this);
            
            frame.add(userIDLabel);
            frame.add(userPasswordLabel);
            frame.add(messageLabel);
            frame.add(userIDField);
            frame.add(userPasswordField);
            frame.add(loginButton);
            frame.add(resetButton);
         
         
         
         frame.add(label);
     }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource()==resetButton) {
            userIDField.setText("");
            userPasswordField.setText("");
        }
        
        if(e.getSource()==loginButton) {
            
            String userID = userIDField.getText();
            String password = String.valueOf(userPasswordField.getPassword());
            
            if(logininfo.containsKey(userID)) {
                if(logininfo.get(userID).equals(password)) {
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.green);
                    messageLabel.setText("Login successful");
                    frame.dispose();
                    
                    try {
                        JAppUser userApp = null;
                        File file = new File("ReservedSeats.ser");
                        if(file.exists()) {
                        FileInputStream filein = new FileInputStream(file);
                        ObjectInputStream in = new  ObjectInputStream(filein);
                            userApp = (JAppUser)in.readObject();
                            in.close();
                            filein.close(); 
                        }
                        else {
                            JAppUser user = new JAppUser();
                        }
                        
                    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                }
                else {
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    messageLabel.setText("Wrong password");
                }

            }
            else {
                messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                messageLabel.setText("username not found");
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

public class JAppUser implements ActionListener, Serializable {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dubai Software Limited");
    JPanel button_panel = new JPanel();
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[50];
    Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 7);

    int count;

    JAppUser() {

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        button_panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 5));
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton();
            buttons[i].setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10);
            button_panel.add(buttons[i]);
            buttons[i].setFocusable(false);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
            buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
        }

        buttons[0].setText("Confirm");

        Integer num = 1;
        for (int j = 5; j < buttons.length; j += 5) {
            String strnum = num.toString();
            buttons[j].setText(strnum);
            num++;
            buttons[j].setEnabled(false);
        }

        String[] buttonName = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        int buttonNum = 0;
        for (int k = 1; k < 5; k++) {
            buttons[k].setText(buttonName[buttonNum]);
            buttonNum++;
            buttons[k].setEnabled(false);
        }

        frame.add(button_panel);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            if (e.getSource() == buttons[i]) {
                if (buttons[i].getText().equals("")) {
                    buttons[i].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                    buttons[i].setText("X");
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Seat  has been reserved.");
                } else if (buttons[i].getText().equals("X")) {
                    buttons[i].setText("");
                    for (int j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++) {
            if (buttons[j].getText().equals("") ||    buttons[j].getText().equals("X")) {
                            buttons[j].setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                    count--;
                    System.out.println("Seat has been unreserved.");
                } else {

                    try {
                   FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("ReservedSeats.ser");
                        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
                        out.writeObject(this);
                        out.close();
                        file.close();
                        System.out.print("Saved Succesfully");

                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    UserIDAndPasswords idandPasswords = new UserIDAndPasswords();
                    UserLogin userlogin = new UserLogin(idandPasswords.getLoginInfo());
                    frame.dispose();
                }
            }
            stop(count);
        }
    }

    public void stop(int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            if (count >= 3) {
                for (int j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++) {
                    if (buttons[i].getText().equals("")) {
                        buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
                        buttons[0].setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, desktop applications, like yours, are hard to handle this type of design you desire. I mean: you are opening the application locally. Another user is opening it in his computer.
You are writting a local file with the information regarding the reservation. So another user, in his computer, won't have access to it.

You have two simple options to solve your problem:

- create a web application that can be used by multiple users simultaneously;
- make your desktop application connect to a database server which can be accessed by multiple users.

In both cases, you can refresh the seat visual interface every "x" seconds/validate if the seat is already reserved before go on.